# How to add datetimepicker in datagridview in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview (DataGridViewsalarydetail). It has 3 columns :

1. Formula(only accept number and alphabet),
2. Effective Date(only accept date ex:14/09/2016),
3. Basic Rate(only accept number and dot[.] for double).

The problem is how to put the date time picker in data grid view OR how to set date column to only accept a valid date ?

I'm using Visual Basic Express 2015, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, and VB.NET

I have tried code from MSDN site, but I don't know how to implement in my project.

```
Private Sub DataGridViewsalarydetail_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewsalarydetail.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
    End If

    If DataGridViewsalarydetail.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress

    ElseIf DataGridViewsalarydetail.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then

        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress2

    ElseIf DataGridViewsalarydetail.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then

        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress1

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

    'If Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) = False Then e.Handled = True

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

    'If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) Or e.KeyChar = ".") Then e.Handled = True
    e.Handled = True
    If e.KeyChar Like "." Or e.KeyChar = Chr(&H8) Or IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox_keyPress2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

    If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) Or e.KeyChar = "/") Then e.Handled = True
    'e.Handled = True
    'If e.KeyChar Like "." Or e.KeyChar Like "/" Or e.KeyChar = Chr(&H8) Or IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
    '    e.Handled = False
    'End If

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridViewsalarydetail_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewsalarydetail.CellValidating
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim dt As DateTime
        If e.FormattedValue.ToString <> String.Empty AndAlso Not DateTime.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString, dt) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter correct Date")
            'Me.DataGridViewsalarydetail.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Enter a valid Date time"
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [datagridview.CellEndEdit event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the user input is correct.

You can use [IsDate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx) like i did in the example below or you can create your own function to verify the user input.

```
Public Sub effectiveDate() Handles DataGridViewsalarydetail.CellEndEdit
    'Get current RowIndex and ColumnIndex
    Dim row As Integer = DataGridViewsalarydetail.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim column As Integer = DataGridViewsalarydetail.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex()

    If column = 1 Then 'If you are currently in the second column of the datagridview
        If IsDate(DataGridViewsalarydetail.Rows(row).Cells(column).Value) = False Then
            MsgBox("The date of the " & row & " row is not correct")
            Dim cell As Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell = DataGridViewsalarydetail.Rows(row).Cells(column)
            'Focus the cell 
            DataGridViewsalarydetail.CurrentCell = cell
            DataGridViewsalarydetail.BeginEdit(True)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried that code . but it give me an error . can you give me an example where can i implement the code ?

Comment: Edit your question and show me some code of your datagridview

Comment: sorry sir , im new in vb code .  so, what should i add to run your code ? and one more thing, can i put date time picker in my datagridview without make a new datagridview?  i mean just put in the existing clolumn.

Comment: if you really need a datetimepicker in your datagridview, check on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx), there is some documentation. You can check [Code Projet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14674/Generic-DataGridView-V) too, there are some sources files that might help you.

Comment: ok sir . thank you very much . now i preparing to present my project . thanks for helping.